# How to convert VARCHAR column cell values to date format?

Tags: mysql, sql, string, datetime

I have customers data translated into DB table in which few cell values in column type Varchar, contains date and few doesnt. The ones that contains Date in certain format, need to be converted into another one which will be further used for data analysis jobs. I tried below query but it shows errors for the cells which doesnt have date. How do I resolve this?

Basically I want to strip off the actual time and append 000000 in place of actual time, along with the date.

[image]

Query:

```
UPDATE Table1 
SET C1 = DATE_FORMAT(C1,'%Y%m%d000000') 
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(C1,'%Y%m%d%H%i%s') AND C1 IS NOT NULL;
```

Error:

> Code : 1292
> Truncated incorrect datetime value: 'EVN'

Comment: Please show us what your data looks like, and which output you want. Note that the error message indicates that you have string `'EVN'` in column `c1` - which sure does not look like a valid date, no matter the format.

Comment: My Data has column C1 which is VARCHAR type. C1 holds multiple date strings and other strings like EVN, ACT etc. Below is the example.  See attached screenshot.

Comment: `DATE_FORMAT()` is for converting a datetime to a string. To go the other way use `STR_TO_DATE()`

Comment: Use `STR_TO_DATE('%m/%d/%y', C1)`

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `STR_TO_DATE()` to parse the date that's in the `VARCHAR` column.

You can use a regular expression to test if the column contains a date in MM/DD/YY format.

```
UPDATE Table1
SET C1 = DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE('%m/%d/%y', C1), '%Y%m%d000000')
WHERE C1 RLIKE '^[01][0-9]/[0-3][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]$'
```

Comment: Nup, Above didnt work since DATE_FORMAT(date, format) is the syntax. What your suggestion does it, tries to find %Y%m%d000000 string and try to convert to date. And what  I am looking for is, find %m/%d/%y and convert to %Y%m%d000000

Comment: I also tried below, but it still shows error/warning for the cell values that are not date.                            UPDATE Table1 SET C1 = DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(C1, '%m/%d/%y'),'%Y%m%d%H%i%s') 
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(C1, '%m/%d/%y'),'%m/%d/%y');                              
Error:                                                                                                                                       1899 row(s) affected, 58 warning(s)
Execution Time : 0.183 sec
Warning Code : 1411  Incorrect datetime value: '2.16.840.1.113883.3.526.3.1006' for function str_to_date

Comment: I can never remember the argument order, I assumed you had it in the correct order in the question instead of checking the documentation. I've changed my answer to use a regular expression instead of calling `STR_TO_DATE()` to test if the column is in the MM/DD/YY format.